# Is it legal to send custom request using cookie?

Tags: httprequest

Is it legal to send custom requests using my own cookie? For example if I login to a website that provides e-mails and I found that I can send a request like: `somewebpage.com?email_id=1&cookie_token=123` then can I send a custom request using eg app written in c++ to get all my emails (by changing email_id)?

Comment: You'd be using this application's internal API. It could change at a moment's notice, but if you're going to be using it for yourself, that shouldn't be too much of an issue. However I can't speak to the legality of this.

Comment: What if I publish this app on github so anyone could use it (but still using their own cookies)?

Comment: You might want to make it clear that you're using an unofficial API so it might break (and require updates) at any time. Again, not sure about legality.